# AWK to use space and forward slash or comma as separator

Tags: shell, awk

I want awk to have 2 separator, i know i could pass it like this,

`awk -F"=|/" '{print $1}'`

However i'm trying pass 2 field separator i.e. space (default fs) and forward slash. I want to extract the ip address from below string.

```
inet 10.190.120.13/24 brd 10.190.120.255 scope global prefixroute eth0
```

Currently i'm using 2 awk statement with pipe and i'm sure there would be better way to achieve this.

```
awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}'
```

Comment: If you want space and slash to be the field separators, have you tried `awk -F' |/' '{print $2}'` or, in case there might be tabs, `awk -F'[[:blank:]]|/' '{print $2}'`?

Comment: @John1024 I think that is worth an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i'm using this with `ip a` command and i did try this way as well but didn't release the ip is in the 6th column, I got the desirable result with this -  

`ip a | grep eth0$ | awk -F'[[:blank:]]|/' '{print $6}'`

Comment: @opensourcejunkie Very good.  If you like, for efficiency, the extra `grep` process can be eliminated: `ip a | awk -F'[[:blank:]]|/' '/eno1$/{print $6}'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with this test file:

```
$ cat file
inet 10.190.120.13/24 brd 10.190.120.255 scope global prefixroute eth0
```

If you want space and slash to be the field separator, try:

```
$ awk -F' |/' '{print $2}' file
10.190.120.13
```

If there is the possibility that your input might have tabs as well as spaces, try:

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:]]|/' '{print $2}' file
10.190.120.13
```

In regular expressions, `|` means *or*.  Thus `|/` (with a space before the vertical bar) means a space *or* a slash.  Awk supports POSIX regular expressions and, under POSIX, `[[:blank:]]` will match any tab or space.

Alternatively, we could put both options in square brackets like:

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:]/]' '{print $2}' file
10.190.120.13
```

If you, as per the title, you want space or slash *or comma* as the separator, try:

```
$ awk -F'[[:blank:]/,]' '{print $2}' file
10.190.120.13
```

Comment: John1024 - thanks for explanation, its very helpful.

Comment: @opensourcejunkie Glad it helped.